# How do I account for repetition within list elements

Tags: python, list

The objective of the parent program is to generate permutations and find out with what probability they are generated by the generating process. I would like help in sorting identical permutations through the list.

So each element in the list is of the form `[[[a,b,c],[x]],[[d,e,f],[y]],....]` where the x represents the probability with which `[a,b,c]` is generated in one loop. I have one of my outputs below.

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [0.125]],[[1, 2, 3], [0.125]],[[2, 3, 1], [0.125]],[[2, 1, 3], [0.125]],[[3, 1, 2], [0.125]],[[1, 2, 3], [0.125]],[[1, 3, 2], [0.125]],[[1, 2, 3], [0.125]]]
```

When my final list contains `[[a,b,c],[x]]` and `[[a,b,c],[y]]`, I will need it to become `[[a,b,c],[x+y]]`. How do I do this?

I tried the following code. The output list is called master_list.

```
for i in range(0,len(master_list)):
    count = []
    for j in range(i+1,len(master_list)):
        if master_list[i][0] == master_list[j][0]:
            count.append(j)
            master_list[i][1][0] += master_list[j][1][0]
        else:
            continue
    print('count for element',master_list[i][0], 'at number', i, 'is', count)
    for k in count:
        print(k)
        for c in range(0,len(count)):
            master_list.remove(master_list[k])
            print('master_list now is',master_list)
            count[c] += -1
```

The print statements were only for me to check. However, the problem I faced was that after every .remove() operation, the indices of the list(s) changed so the loop broke down.

Comment: Perhaps add what you tried to solve it

Comment: Yes I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating the original list removing element from there (list.remove() is O(n) [[ref]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), a more efficient way is to pass through an intermediary dictionary for then creating again a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = [[[1, 2, 3], [0.125]], [[1, 2, 3], [0.125]], [[2, 3, 1], [0.125]], [[2, 1, 3], [0.125]], [[3, 1, 2], [0.125]],
       [[1, 2, 3], [0.125]], [[1, 3, 2], [0.125]], [[1, 2, 3], [0.125]]]

grouped_res = defaultdict(float)
for perm, prob in res:
    grouped_res[tuple(perm)] += prob[0]


new_res = [[list(k), [v]] for k, v in grouped_res.items()]
# [[[1, 2, 3], [0.5]], [[2, 3, 1], [0.125]], [[2, 1, 3], [0.125]], [[3, 1, 2], [0.125]], [[1, 3, 2], [0.125]]]
```